# How to change the color of Scrollbar in JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the JScrollPane Scrollbar color to black. I tried to make the change using UIManger. but found nothing.

Answer (score 9):

To change the background color of the scroll bar, you can do this:

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

To change the color of the scrollbar itself, use the following code:

```
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;

scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI() {
    @Override
    protected void configureScrollBarColors() {
        this.thumbColor = Color.BLACK;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank @Julian Peffer, but from this, I'm only able to change the background color of the scroll bar but I also want to change the bar color.

Comment: Just add this to your code: I also put it in the answer.                                                                                                                  scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI()
  {
   @Override
   protected void configureScrollBarColors()
   {
    this.thumbColor = Color.BLACK;
   }
  });